# Sum time difference and pivot it - pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe has two columns: unix_time and user. It has thousands of rows, this is part of it:

```
unix_time       user
2000000000000   A
2000000000001   A
2000000000002   B
2000000000003   B
2000000000004   B
```

I want to calculate how much unix_time each user spent in total by:
1. calculating time difference between rows. eg: `unix_time column (row2 - row1)`
2. sum the time difference if they are from the same user. eg: `sum(row2 - row1) and (row3 - row2)`

output will be

```
time_difference_sum  user
1                    A
2                    B
```

I read several posts such as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47385719/date-time-difference-and-dataframe-filtering) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-pandas-dataframe-time-difference-between-two-columns-in-hours-and-minu) but still struggle to find a solution because I got more constraints. Any suggestions about how can I do this ?  Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby()` and `diff()` and then `agg()` your results:

```
df['time_difference_sum'] = df.sort_values(['user','unix_time']).groupby('user')['unix_time'].diff()

df.groupby('user').agg({'time_difference_sum': 'sum'})
```

Yields:

```
      time_difference_sum
user                     
A                     1.0
B                     2.0
```

Comment: Thank you but I got error `Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1` when I tried on real data. I wonder is that because in real data user B may have smaller unix_time than user A although the row number is later than user A?

Comment: Do you have more columns in your original dataframe than you show in your question? See my edit, which may resolve that issue.

Comment: sure thank you! `unix_time user
1417412578004 i2wl1o1n5wsoahi066uf
1417412581732 i2wl1o1n5wsoahi066uf
1417412581733 i2wl1o1n5wsoahi066uf
1417412581733 i2wl1o1n5wsoahi066uf
1417412590099 i2wl1o1n5wsoahi066uf
1417412591780 i2wl1o1n5wsoahi066uf
1417412596325 i2wl1o1n5wsoahi066uf
1417412596326 i2wl1o1n5wsoahi066uf
1417412600171 i2wl1o1n5wsoahi066uf
1417412600171 i2wl1o1n5wsoahi066uf
1417412600172 i2wl1o1n5wsoahi066uf
1417412604687 i2wl1o1n5wsoahi066uf
1417412647448 i2wl1o1n5wsoahi066uf
1417412649678 i2wl1o1n5wsoahi066uf`